# How to select 10 records above and below row according to a double conditional in SQL

Tags: sql, parse-platform

I have run into a problem when creating a high score table for my app.

Basically, I want to be able to query a server (parse) for 10 records above and below the user's high score record and display something like this:

- 45 username ...
- 46 username ...
- 47 username ...
- 48 username ...
- 49 username ...
- 50 username ...
- 51 username ...
- 52 username ...
- 53 username ...
- 54 username ...
- **55 USER'S HIGH SCORE**
- 55 username ...
- 56 username ...
- 57 username ...
- 58 username ...
- 59 username ...
- 60 username ...
- 61 username ...
- 62 username ...
- 63 username ...
- 64 username ...

Technically, I am not using SQL, I am using the Parse IOS API. But the logic is the same so if I can figure out how to do it in SQL, I can do it using the Parse API.

An seemingly simple solution would be to find the user's high score and run a query for 10 records where the score is greater than the user's and join that with a query for 10 records below the user's.

This doesn't work because when two user's have the same high score (this will happen often in this app) I want to show the user who obtained the high score first as being above the others. For instance, if Bill scored 41 on Nov 1st and Bob scored 41 on Nov 2nd, Bill would be above Bob on the ranking table.

The two columns that I am using to sort are:

- highScore : Number
- createdAt : Date

This double conditional is easy to implement if I am just finding the top 50 scores or something like that but I can't figure out how to center the query around a single record.

**EDIT (my temporary solution)**
I found a temporary solution that works but is not perfect:

Split the query into 4 queries:

- q1: highScore > userScore; Descending->highScore; Ascending->createdAt; Limit 10
- q2: highScore == userScore; createdAt <= userDate; Descending->highScore; Ascending->createdAt; Limit 10
- q3: highScore == userScore; createdAt > userDate; Descending->highScore; Ascending->createdAt; Limit 10
- q4: highScore < userScore; Descending->highScore; Ascending->createdAt; Limit 10

Then, if q2 returns less than 10 records, fill the remaining ones using q1. If q3 returns less than 10 records, fill it with q4. At most, this returns only 40 records to display 20, so this will work with not much wasted querying.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I don't know the exact one that Parse.com uses, I am just using their database API syntax which is essentially creating an SQL command piece by piece, then running it and letting their API do all the network stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can do this with a `union` all, first to get the 11 rows with higher or equal scores and then the 10 rows with lower scores:

```
(select s.*
 from scores s
 where s.score >= (select max(score) from scores where user = $USER)
 order by s.score asc
 limit 11
)
union all
(select s.*
 from scores s
 where s.score <= (select max(score) from scores where user = $USER) and users <> $USER
 order by s.score desc
 limit 10
)
```

Comment: This could give you a result _without_ the row of the user if there are more than 11 rows with the same score.

Comment: Also, there could be people above and below the user with the same score but different dates like this: 45 - person:score(23):date(Nov 1) ... 46 - USER:score(23):date(Nov 2) ... 47 - person:score(23):date(Nov 4)